# Using sum in hibernate criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

How can I express this query in hibernate criteria??

```
select SUM (tabla2.valor1) 
  from tabla1 INNER JOIN 
       tabla2 ON tabla1.ID = tabla2.ID 
 where tabla1.ID = 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's your entity looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Projections` , something like

```
getSessionFactory() //this is the session factory, initialized with->  new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory()
    .openSession()
    .createCriteria(tabla1.class)
    .createAlias("tabla2.id", "tab2", JoinType.INNER_JOIN)
    .setProjection(Projections.sum("tab2.valor1"));
```